# What do the numbers in launchctl list's status column mean?

Tags: mac-osx, launchd, launchctl

launchctl has a "Status" column in the launchctl list output.  The manpage or any of the related launchd manpages do not mention this column or what it means.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is the last exit code of that service.

The `launchctl` man page describes it.

```
 list [-x] [label]
          With no arguments, list all of the jobs loaded
          into launchd in three columns. The first column
          displays the PID of the job if it is running.
          The second column displays the last exit status
          of the job. If the number in this column is
          negative, it represents the negative of the
          signal which killed the job.  Thus, "-15" would
          indicate that the job was terminated with
          SIGTERM. The third column is the job's label.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm on 10.5 they added this in the 10.6 manpage.  (If you go to Apple's page and choose 10.5 you can see it lacks the above bit http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.5/man1/launchctl.1.html )

Comment: If you don't know what the codes mean [Unix Signals](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~alanjawi/cs449/code/shell/UnixSignals.htm) is the search term you want.

Comment: @DaveNoonan `man signal` too